# ax.grid overwrites ticks labels when spine is in centre

Tags: python, matplotlib

When using ax.grid() and moving the spines to the middle of the plot, the grid lines go over the axes labels. Any way to stop this and move the axes labels to "front"?

EDIT: It is the ticks labels (the numbers) I'm interested in fixing, not the axis label, which can be easily moved.

EDIT: made the MWE and image match exactly

EDIT: matplotlib version 2.0.0

[image]

```
#!/usr/bin/env python                                                                                

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

fig = plt.figure()
ax = plt.gca()
ax.minorticks_on()

ax.grid(b=True, which='major', color='k', linestyle='-',alpha=1,linewidth=1)
ax.grid(b=True, which='minor', color='k', linestyle='-',alpha=1,linewidth=1)

x = np.linspace(-5,5,100)
y = np.linspace(-5,5,100)

plt.plot(x,y)

plt.yticks([-5,-4,-3,-2,-1,0,1,2,3,4,5])
ax.spines['left'].set_position(('data', 0))

plt.show()
```

Comment: The code you posted doesn't create the figure you show. If I run the code you've shown it's not obvious that the grid lines are actually on top of the spines. Could you show the code that reproduces that figure?

Comment: The problem is that this is not reproducible. Running your code as it is, already has the numbers above the grid lines. Using some alpha different from 1 may also not help in clearly showing the issue (better use thick opaque lines, `alpha=1, linewidth=3`), clearly state which version of matplotlib you are using.

Comment: I ran your example with matplotlib 2.0.2 (I don't have an environment with 2.0.0 available) and the [result is still as expected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CQg2d.png). If you need version 2.0, I would recommend updating to 2.0.2. If there is no special reason to use this particular version, directly go with 2.2.2.